# fo:inline + wrap-option="no-wrap" not working

Tags: apache-fop

I need to make certain text blocks non-wraping e.g.:

<fo:block>

This is to confirm that .. blalb long text ... **<fo:inline wrap-option="no-wrap"><xsl:value-of select='$name' /></fo:inline>**
</fo:block>

What I need is that text inside **<fo:inline>** would'nt wrap. But is wraps right now, despide **wrap-option="no-wrap"** 
How could I display certain text so that it never wraps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">This will all be kept together on a line,  even squeezed to unreadable, or the product you have selected to format your FO is garbage</fo:inline>
```

Now, if your product cuts this off at the end or squeezes the text to fit ... it's your decision what to use, some squeeze, some cut.

Hint: Squeezing is the right answer in the above example.